# IMFMediaSourceTopologyProvider::GetMediaSourceTopology always fails, why?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

Under what circumstances the `IMFMediaSourceTopologyProvider::GetMediaSourceTopology()` does not fail? It always fails with code 0xc00d36e6 (`MF_E_ATTRIBUTENOTFOUND`). 
Please do not answer with a link to MSDN.

Comment: Is it too hard to explain why should this be closed? There are no resources on the internet describing this issue. Only one bad book written by Anton Polinger where he basically printed the MSDN contents on Windows Media Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution after pissing blood for hours.

You have to call QueryInterface() on IMFSequencerSource object to get the IMFMediaSource like this:

```
hr = pMFSequencerSrc->QueryInterface( __uuidof( IMFMediaSource ), (void**)&pMediaSource );
```

Now on `pMediaSource` object call `CreatePresentationDescriptor()` to get the presentation descriptor required for the `GetMediaSourceTopology()` call.

voila...

P.S.
That MF_E_ATTRIBUTENOTFOUND error... nice work M$

Comment: FWIW, getting the `IMFPresentationDescriptor*` is explained on MSDN here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx